# How make Yii condition on Many_Many relations

Tags: php, yii, yii-relations

have tables:

```
    place (id, title, state);
movie (id, title, state);
schedule (place_id, movie_id, time);
```

use simple yii models:

```
    place.relations:
'movies' => array( self::MANY_MANY, 'movie', 
               'schedule(place_id,movie_id)', 
               'condition' => 'time > now()' ),
```

use simple yii controller:

```
    $tmp = new Place();
$res = $tmp->findAll();
var_dump( $res[0]->movies );
```

yii returns a full list with the out state status :(

How can I get movies with the condition movie.state = 1 ?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your relations correctly, this should work.

```
$res = Place::model()->with('movies')->findAll(array('condition'=>'movies.state =1'));
```

In any case, consult the documentation for more advanced query options :) http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#find-detail

Answer (score 1):

If it's a conditional state:

```
$state = $_POST['state'];
$res = Place::model()->with('movies')->findAll(array('condition'=>'movies.state=:m_state', 'params'=>array(':m_state'=>$state)));
```

Depending on version of Yii, you can remove the ':' in the array keys of params.
Read up about them and mark the previous answer as best already.